# How to add text and images to the page in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I created a tabbed page app that has three different pages, each page has a title and an icon,  but I don't know how to add text to each page.

```
var page1 = new ContentPage()
{
    Title = "",
    Icon = "icone1",

};
var page2 = new ContentPage()
{
    Title = "",
    Icon = "icone2",

};
var page3 = new ContentPage()
{
    Title = "",
    Icon = "icone3"
};

// The root page of your application
var content = new TabbedPage()
{
    Title = "TabbedPage",



    Children = {
            page1,
            page2,
            page3
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
page1.Content = new StackLayout 
{ 
    Children = { 
        new Label { Text = "Hello, World" }, 
        new Button { Text = "I'm a button" }
    }
};
```

However, a better approach is to create a new file for each page that inherits from `ContentPage`.  This is much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much